# Android GridView Background Highlights

Tags: android, android-gridview

Normally in the Gridview, while you are pressing on an element in the grid, it highlights the specific squares background with a nice orange'ish well defined. I want to make it stay highlighted after you let go as well, basically turn it into a toggle on/off for the highlights. I want to use the android highlight color that's built in automatically but I have so far been unsuccessful in any attempt to get this to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use `android:listSelector="#00000000"` in your GridView element in your XML layout file.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting

```
setDrawSelectorOnTop(true)
```

This draws selector over the selected item.